# MongoDB - get data from ID on the fly

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, backend

I have this sample data

Posts

```
[{
 _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
 name: 'Foo'
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
 name: 'Bar'
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("5b8797747ea41163b7eb51b0"),
 name: 'FooBar'
}]
```

Categories

```
[{
 _id: ObjectId("5b87979c10397d6c12d69513"),
 name: 'Funny',
 type: 1
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("5b8797ab24098febfb05abdd"),
 name: 'Sad',
 type: 1
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("5b8797b24e31ebf7603f3c3e"),
 name: 'Romantic',
 type: 2
}]
```

And the last one is relationships

```
[{
 _id: ObjectId("5b879818763ecd6f1c54d306"),
 postID: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
 categoryID: ObjectId("5b87979c10397d6c12d69513")
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("5b8798eb040890fb2a88c0af"),
 postID: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
 categoryID: ObjectId("5b8797b24e31ebf7603f3c3e"),
}]
```

When I use a $lookup in Mongo I get something like this:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
 name: 'Foo', 
 categories: [{
     _id: ObjectId("5b879818763ecd6f1c54d306"),
     postID: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
     categoryID: ObjectId("5b87979c10397d6c12d69513")
  },
  {
     _id: ObjectId("5b8798eb040890fb2a88c0af"),
     postID: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
     categoryID: ObjectId("5b8797b24e31ebf7603f3c3e"),
  }]
}
```

In this case, this is my all example data in relationships, anyway how to get just categories data instead of relationships data, I want to get something like this:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
 name: 'Foo', 
 categories: [{
     _id: ObjectId("5b87979c10397d6c12d69513"),
     name: 'Funny',
     type: 1
   },
   {
     _id: ObjectId("5b8797b24e31ebf7603f3c3e"),
     name: 'Romantic',
     type: 2
   }]
}
```

Comment: Is there one to one relation between all three collections? and what is your mongodb version?

Comment: Yup, like in Wordpress and his taxonomy, my mongo version is higher than 3.6, sorry I cannot type exactly version cause I don’t have my computer right now

Comment: No problem it can be easily done with mongodb 3.6

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation from mongodb **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011") } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Relationship",
    "let": { "categoryID": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$categoryID", "$$categoryID" ] } } },
       { "$lookup": {
         "from": "Category",
         "let": { "categoryID": "$categoryID" },
         "pipeline": [
           { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$categoryID" ] } } }
         ],
         "as": "category"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$category" },
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$category" }}
    ],
    "as": "categories"
  }}
])
```

Comment: chapeau bas mate :)